# notepad++ nppgtag plugin shortcut

Tags: editor, notepad++, text-editor

I have installed npp plugins from sourceforge [nppgtags](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppgtags/) on latest notepad++ version but i am not able to effectively use that. I am facing these problem

1. Is there any shortcut for nppgtags plugin of notepad to search references, create DB, search definition and other command?
2. On the sourceforge page the image of the plugin have 3 windows

   nppgtags

   doc-switcher

   tag-view

but i am only getting nppgtags window. am i missing something here or i need to install some other plugin for effectively using it.

adding image url: [image of the plugin on notepad++](http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/nppgtags/screenshots/FindDefinition.png)

Answer (score 3):

Got answer from developer on sourcefourge. [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/nppgtags/discussion/general/thread/62ce1e60/?limit=25#0bce)

**I want to know if this plugin has any keyboard shortcut in it.**

I haven't predefined any shortcuts on purpose because when you have a lot of plugins those might have conflicting shortcut keys. So I've left the shortcut definitions to the user and to his preference.
To set a shortcut in Notepad++ go to the Settings menu, Shortcut Mapper... . Chose Plugin Commands, find NppGTags commands in the list and define whatever shortcuts you need. Those will be saved in your Notepad++ config folder, shortcuts.xml file.

**what are the other plugin you are using in that.**

The one on the left is actually Notepad++ internal function - Doc Switcher. Go to Notepad++ Settings menu, Preferences... , select General. Find there Document List Panel and mark Show + optionally Disable extension column as it is in my case.
The one on the right is TagsView plugin. It is available through PluginManager and can be also found in SourceForge if you search for it.
The names of the plugins can actually be seen from their windows titles. Just look at the screenshots, above each plugin's sub-window. There is written its name.