# How to add hotkey shortcut to a plugin function?

Tags: notepad++

**Is it possible to add a hotkey combo to 'Format T-SQL Code' below?**
**It is for 'Poor man's T-sql formatter plugin.**
[image]

**I checked, and no option in the plugins options itself:**
[image]

Comment: Believe the answer in this one will help. It worked for me. <https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406212>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406212 Didnt see the plugin commands tab at the Shortcut mapper